# how to do this with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to practice for loops and I cannot get the for loop to do this for me, how can I have the code that would give me this result ?

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I know simple for loop

```
    for(int y = 1; y <= 10; y++){




        System.out.println(y);
        }
```

result

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: try without `...ln` suffix.

Comment: I did , I got weird numbers lol...my placing is off

Comment: Did you really mean to skip `2` on the vertical axis?

Comment: oops typo...but I am glad I did...its a good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {

        System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int y = 3; y <= 10; y++) {

        System.out.println(y);
    }
```

Comment: Note that this skips the number `2`, which matches the OP's expected output. (Starting with `y=3` in the second loop isn't a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  System.out.print(i);
  if (i == 1) {
    for (int t = i + 1; t < 11; t++) {
      System.out.print(" " + t);
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```